# set some diagonal elements of a matrix in Matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, diagonal

A quick question, I have a sparse matrix A and a index list `b = [2, 3, 4 ...]`, I want to set  `A(2, 2), A(3, 3), A(4, 4)... = 0`. I tried A(b, b) = 0, the result is that `A(2, 3), A(2, 4), A(3, 2), A(3, 4), A(4, 2), A(4, 3)` and some non-diagonal elements of this matrix are also set zero, how to deal with that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [linear indexing](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/sub2ind.html):

```
A(sub2ind(size(A),b,b)) = 0;
```

This works for full or sparse matrices.